# AWS ECS: no container instance met all of its requirements

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ecs

We have an ECS cluster with 3 EC2 instances. In this cluster we have a bunch of services running, all separate apps with 1 task.

Frequently when I try to run a new service, ECS tries to run the task in an EC2 instance with not enough memory/CPU, while there is a different instance available with more than enough. In fact, there are now 2 instances with both 5 tasks, and 1 instance with only 1.

What could be the reason of this weird division of tasks? I've tried every possible task placement strategy but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Most recent error message:

```
service [service name] was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance [instance-id] has insufficient memory available.
```

Comment: How are you determining that the other instances have "more than enough"? What are the CPU and memory requests for the task? How much does the instance with the most available have?

Comment: Task reserves 350 CPU and 512 memory. Instance with most available has 1698 CPU and 1613 memory.